# find out if any combination of elements in the array sums to a specific size

Tags: java

I am trying to find out if any combination of elements in the array sums to a specific size or not.

For e.g. 
input: {Sizes: [1,1,3,5], Goal: 2} output: Yes/No => Yes in this case as 1+1 = 2

One of the solutions i can think of is more of a brute force solution, where i will have n^2 tries to find a size specific to goal.

i.e. something like this :

```
for(i=0; i< array.size(); i++) {
    for(j=i+1; j< array.size(); j++) {
        if(i+j == goal) {
           return true;
        }
    }
}
```

is this the only approach ? also, is my code correct for the same ?

By 'combination', I don't mean 'pair' (must be exactly two items) but an actual combination (where it could be anywhere from 0 to all of the items)

Comment: This code will only work if TWO of the numbers add up to the goal.

Comment: When you say 'combination', do you mean 'pair' (must be exactly two items) or an actual combination (where it could be anywhere from 0 to all of the items)?

Comment: no it is not 2, it can be more than 2 as well.

Comment: Is this not the Knapsack Problem?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Your code is not correct. It only looks for 2-combinations. What if your goal were 9. You could get that as 1+3+5 but your code can't find it.

Comment: A working brute force solution would be getting all possible subsets of given list, sum up the elements of each list and compare the sums with the goal.

Comment: you can have two dimension array where first index will have value only if your original array contains particular value. and corresponding 2nd dimension index will have counter. in your case suppose `{1,1,3,5}`. create `int arr[][];` while assigning value that can be like  `{{1,2},{2,0},{3,1},{4,0},{5,1}}; ` so you can search as you want whatever number directly at that index. for 2 index 1 is having value means 1 is there and its counter is 2 so you got the answer.

Comment: If you don't have any negative numbers in your lists you can eliminate all numbers larger than your target value, thus reducing the number of combinations you need to look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a slightly stricter version of the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). In short, there is no "best" way to solve it, as it is an NP-Complete problem.

If anyone has found a single optimal way to solve this problem, I encourage you to write a paper on it at once, submitting it to the ACM and IEEE, and enjoy your newfound wealth and fame.

I don't have any real experience with these sort of problems, but I did play around with [genetic algorithms](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~nd/surprise_96/journal/vol1/hmw/article1.html) in college which are decently successful at this sort of thing. I'd give that a go, personally.

If you're dealing with data sets as small as are in your problem, you're probably best just brute forcing it. For a group of 5 numbers, there are at most 325 possible permutations, which wouldn't take too long to iterate through. Less time if you made common sense optimizations like neuronaut suggested in comments.

The upshot is that you have a [relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/287/). Enjoy.

[image]

Comment: ha ha.. you made my day... but yeah i am still stuck at the problem .. totally clueless now

Comment: Its one of the classic problems of computer science. Read up on the knapsack problem, find a solution that you like, and implement it.

Comment: See my edit - if this is just a school/personal project, do a genetic algorithm. They're pretty rad.

Comment: I don't think a genetic algorithm would work for this problem. They are great when you need a result approaching optimal (as with the traveling salesman where any short-ish path is acceptable), but this problem seems to require an exact solution.

Comment: Not a school project. I am out of school :P .. yep i can try genetic.. thanks for the links. I may mark this as an answer

Comment: @neuronaut - GAs can find optimal solutions in reasonable time if the problem set is sufficiently small. I'm not saying its perfect, or even the best option, but I think it would work (dependent upon the scale he's working at).

Comment: @CodeMonkey for what purpose do you need this code? Knowing a bit more about the application can yield better answers. I wouldn't use a GA if you had problem sets in the thousands and needed an answer in seconds. Though, if thats the case, you're probably doomed anyways.

Comment: @JeremyBarnes Yes, they can find an optimal solution (that's what I mean by "any short-ish path") but using a GA to find an _exact_ solution will usually take longer than the brute force method. And if your data set is small, why would you use a GA since brute force will find the answer just as fast? I'm not nocking GAs - they VERY useful - I just don't think it's the best solution in this particular case.

Comment: @neuronaut - having never used one in the real world, I can't speak to their value there. But I sort of think that for datasets around ~25, brute force would take longer, but a GA might be very quick. 25 is, to my mind, a smallish dataset.

Comment: @JeremyBarnes The problem with a GA in this particular case is that there's no way for it to "home in" on a more and more optimal solution. The result can only be "yes" (the list has at least one combo that sums to the goal value) or "no" (no such combo exists). So a GA would degenerate into a brute force solution, but with the added overhead involved with the "genetics" aspect.

Comment: @neuronaut I'm not so sure - a chromosome that was "close" to the optimal solution is worth saving and playing with, which is what GAs are for. I take your point though.

Comment: @JeremyBarnes hmm... I suppose if you look chromosomes that get a close result (say, a sum of 7 or 9 when the goal is 8) that could be useful if you are sure the list contains a combo that sums to the goal. The problem here is that the only way to get a "no" result for a list is to eliminate ALL combinations, which makes a GA pointless.

Comment: @neuronaut I will grant that. Still fun.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research it turns out that the problem described here is not the knapsack problem. The knapsack problems requires that each item going into the knapsack have 2 variables (usually a mass and a value) and to solve it you must choose a combination of items that add up to no more than the maximum mass allowed by the knapsack **and** that combination must be the one with the greatest sum of values. It's this pairing of requirements that makes the knapsack problem NP-complete since it means computing all combinations in order to choose the one with the greatest value.

This problem, however, has only a single variable per item: the size. As such it is not NP-complete and can be solved quite easily and quickly, even with large inputs.

```
private List<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<Integer> ();

private boolean hasGoalSum(List<Integer> list, int goal)
{
    // this if statement is the key to making this algorithm fast
    // since the algorithm is recursive it ends up eliminating many combinations
    // that don't need to be tested
    if (list.isEmpty () || goal > sumList(list) || goal < Collections.min (list))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // next we remove items from the list that are greater than the goal
    // since the can't be used to sum up to the goal
    list = rejectIfGreaterThanGoal (list, goal);
    if (list.contains (goal))
    {
        solution.add (goal);
        return true;
    }

    // if we don't have a solution yet we take the biggest item from the list and
    // and check if combining it with any of the remaining items will result
    // in an answer. If not, we then recursively call with a smaller list a
    // new subgoal. If there's still no solution we move to the next biggest
    // item in the list and so on until exhausting the list or finding a solution.
    while (!list.isEmpty ())
    {
        int m = Collections.max (list);
        list.remove ((Integer) m);
        if (list.contains (goal - m))
        {
            solution.add (m);
            solution.add (goal - m);
            return true;
        }
        if (hasGoalSum (list, goal - m))
        {
            solution.add (m);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private int sumList (List<Integer> list)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer num : list)
    {
        sum += num;
    }
    return sum;
}

private List<Integer> rejectIfGreaterThanGoal (List<Integer> list, int goal)
{
    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<> ();
    for (Integer i : list)
    {
        if (i <= goal)
        newList.add (i);
    }
    return newList;
}
```

I included the class member variable `solution` here so you can print it out to see the find solution in cases where the returned boolean (as requested by the OP) isn't enough.

I should also note that the problem in the cartoon is essentially the same as this problem and can thus be solved by the same algorithm. Just create a list with a number of each dish where the price is equal to or less than the goal (e.g. the list would contain seven 2.15 entries, five 2.75 entries, etc.) and then feed that to the `hasGoalSum` method along with the goal of 15.05. With cartoon's problem it's more interesting to see the `solution` than the boolean result of the `hasGoalSum` method.

The cartoon's problem would have been the knapsack problem (and thus NP-complete) if each appetizer had a number of calories assigned and the request to the waiter was to bring not only exactly $15.05 worth of appetizers but to bring the combination with the least number of calories.

Answer (score 0):

Use Knapsack and make the weight[] = valuesOrProfit[]

Call the Algo like
Integer[] response = KnapsackSolver(weight,valuesOrProfit, finalWeight);

to get the Solution.

Here finalWeight is nothing but the exact sum that you are trying to match.!!!

This will work if you do not have a constraint that only TWO numbers should be Equal to the Final Weight (finalWeight) as mentioned in the question.!!!

Good Luck!!!